# find dates within the provided time range

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to store an array of objects that contain the property `event_timestamp` that contains a `Date()` object of the timestamp of the event.

i'll like to provide a from `Date` object and a to `Date` object and to collect all the objects within that range.

I don't want to iterate over all the array, i'd like something faster... for example `O(Log N)` or anything else.

is there something like that implemented in javascript? is there a 3rd party library that provides the search by `O(Log N)` or any other fast method?

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thanks!

## update

thanks for your responses so far.

my scenario is that i have a dashboard that contains graphs. now user can search for example.. give me the result of the last 15 minutes. then the server provide rows with the relevant results and each row in the result contains a property called `event_timestamp` that contains a `Date` Object.

now, if after 5 minutes the user searches for the last 15 minutes again, then it means that the first 10 minutes he already queried before, so I want to cache that and to send a request from the server only for the last 5 minutes.

so whenever the user queries the server, i take the response and parse it using the following steps:

1. get event_time on first row
2. get event_time of last row
3. append to an array the following object:

   {
    rows: rows,
    fromDate: firstRowDate,
    toDate: lastRowDate
   }

now.. in the previous example the user first queries for 15 minutes, and after 5 minutes queried for 15 minutes again. which means i have 10 valuable minutes of data in the object.

the main issue here is how do i iterate over the rows fast to find the relevant rows that i need to use for my graph.

in a simple way i can just iterate through all the rows and find the ones that are in the range of `fromDate` to `toDate`. but if i'll deal with a few million rows that's gonna be a hassle for the client.

I use google flat buffer to transfer the data and then I build the rows by myself. so I can save them in any other format.

hope this helps understand my needs. thanks!

Comment: A `Date` object has both date and time. When you say from `Date` to `Date`, what is your resolution? Every second, minute, hour, day, etc...?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan - the resolution is second, even millisecond if possible.

Comment: There are JavaScript SQL libraries out there that will probably help. Add the information to a "table" that you can query. ... `find all rows where fromDate >= ... and toDate <= ...` or something like that

Comment: Also, with a few million rows, can JavaScript even handle that? Won't it slow down a browser? Have you tried doing a test run to see if you can even store millions of rows in an array?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan - i didn't test. I will test and limit the cache to the amount of rows appropriate by the browser.

Comment: I don't think your way of approaching this is a good idea, but i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

With your current way of storage there is no other or faster way than to iterate over the whole array. So your complexity will be `O(n)` just for traversing the array.

The information you need to access is stored inside an object which itself is stored in the array. How else would you be able to access the information than to look at each single object. Even in other languages with different array implementations, there wouldn't be a faster way.

The only way you could make this faster is by changing the way you store your data.

For example you could implement a [BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) with the date as the index. As this would be sorted by date, you wouldn't have to traverse the whole tree and you would need fewer operations to find the nodes in range. I'm afraid you would have to build it yourself though.

**Update:**

This was related to your initial question. Your update goes in a whole new direction.

I don't think your approach is a good idea. You won't be able to handle such a big amount of data, at least not in a performant way. Why not query the server more often, based on what the client really needs. You could even adjust the resolution, as you might not need all the points, depending on how large the chosen range is.

Nonetheless, if we can assume the array you got is already sorted by date, you can find your matching values faster with a [Binary Search Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

This is how it would basically work: You start in the middle of your array, if the found number is higher than the one you are looking for, you inspect the left half of your array, if it is lower, you inspect the right one. Now you you inspect the middle of your new section. You continue with this pattern until you've found your value.

[image: Visualization of the binary search algorithm where 4 is the target value.]

*Visualization of the binary search algorithm where 4 is the target value.*

The average performance of a Binary Search Algorithm is `O(log n)`, so this would definitely help.

This is just a start to give you an idea. You will need to modify it a bit, to work with your range.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I can store my data differently.  Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @ufk: If you elaborate more on what you are trying to do and why then we might be able to point you in the right direction.